# What is the shortest code to get surrounding coordinates?

Tags: swift, swift3

I don't like my following implementation of `surroundingPositions` to get the x- and y-Coordinates surrounding a specific position, because in my opinion it is too long for the simple intent and it has a pyramid of doom structure.

```
struct Position: CustomStringConvertible {

    let x, y: Int

    var surroundingPositions: [Position] {
        var surroundingPositions: [Position] = []
        for x in (self.x - 1)...(self.x + 1) {
            for y in (self.y - 1)...(self.y + 1) {
                if !(x == self.x && y == self.y) {
                    surroundingPositions.append(Position(x: x, y: y))
                }
            }
        }
        return surroundingPositions
    }

    var description: String {
        return "(\(x),\(y))"
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let testPosition = Position(x: 1, y: 1)
print(testPosition.surroundingPositions)
// Output: [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]
```

What is the shortest way to implement this with the same (correct) result? I'm thinking of functions like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc., but can't find the right combination so far ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could always hardcode it. Here, I hardcoded the deltas and create a new `Position` for each delta:

```
var surroundingPositionsHardcoded: [Position] {
    let deltas: [(Int, Int)] = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, +1), (0, -1), (0, +1), (+1, -1), (+1, 0), (+1, +1)]
    return deltas.map { Position(x: x+$0.0, y: y+$0.1) }
}
```

Or, you could compute the deltas using `map`. This has the added benefit that you could increase the surrounding distance.

```
var surroundingPositionsComputed: [Position] {
    let deltas = (-1...1).map { dx in (-1...1).map { dy in (dx, dy) } }
        .joined()
        .filter { $0.0 != 0 || $0.1 != 0 }
    return deltas.map { Position(x: x+$0.0, y: y+$0.1) }
}
```

Comment: Especially the second solution was what I was looking for. Short and elegant, thanks!

Comment: I should point out (for possible future readers) that the second approach should not be preferred if the neighbourhood "radius" is a constant (which it is in this example: `1`). Possibly the compiler will optimize the `deltas` computation to a single call, but then I would advice putting the `filter` call on the `deltas` instantiation rather than at the `return` call, as (given a constant "radius") we don't really want to perform the filtering of constants vs. constants for each call to the _computation_ of the surrounding positions given a position instance. For a varying radius, go for #2!

Comment: I second what @dfri says. I actually had the filter on the deltas creation but put it on the second line to have shorter lines. I updated the post applying dfri`s suggestion and added a few linebreaks. If the distance is (and will be) a constant you could certainly go ahead and make this a static variable like it is in dfri's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only look for the neighbouring positions and seemingly have no constraint on `x` or `y`, you could save an array of `(x, y)` translations that each maps a given `Position` to one of its 8 different neighbouring ones.

```
struct Position: CustomStringConvertible {
    let x, y: Int

    // order of resulting neighbouring positions, given a position P
    // (1)  (2)  (3)
    // (4)  (P)  (5)
    // (6)  (7)  (8)
    private static let surroundingPositionsTranslations: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [
        (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
        (-1,  0),          (1,  0),
        (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]

    var surroundingPositions: [Position] {
        return Position.surroundingPositionsTranslations
            .map { Position(x: x + $0.x, y: y + $0.y) }
    }

    var description: String {
        return "(\(x),\(y))"
    }
}

// Note that I've changed the order w.r.t. OP:s original code
// (modify the transfotmation above to modify the order)
let testPosition = Position(x: 1, y: 1)
print(testPosition.surroundingPositions)
// Output: [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (2,1), (0,0), (1,0), (2,0)]
```

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than what I have so far. However I accepted another answer that has the same content (hardcoded) plus an even more flexible and elegant solution (computed). Thanks for your answer nevertheless!

Comment: @BennoKress happy to help. Yes I noticed we posted somewhat the same content at the same time :) just make sure to prefer the "hardcoded" one in case you don't have a various radius for the neighbourhood (as in your example: static and set to `1`), as the "computed" approach, for a constant radius, will needlessly perform, upon each call, a nested `map`, an array initialization etc (possibly optimizable by the compiler) followed by a needless `filter` just to filter out the single `self` coordinate that we may already omit if using a set of static "hardcoded" transformations.