# Swift mapping tuples in a closure

Tags: swift, struct, tuples

I have a struct called Grid that is 10 cells x 10 cells, and ***I need to determine the position of a given cell's neighboring cells.***

Every cell has a position ranging from (0,0) to (9,9). Position is `typealias Position = (row: Int, col: Int)`. *norm* normalizes positions like makes sure that something like (12,0) gets mapped back to the 10x10 grid as (2,0).

```
func norm(_ val: Int, to size: Int) -> Int {
    return ((val % size) + size) % size
}
```

This extension to Grid is supposed to determine the position of all neighboring cells given a cell like (6,3). ***I've commented out the part that I'm trying to figure out.*** I'm trying to run norm on the x and y coordinates of the neighbors to determine their actual position.

```
extension Grid {
    func neighbors(of cell: Cell) -> [Position] {
        // return Grid.offsets.map{(norm($0, to: rows)), (norm($1, to: cols))}
    }
}
```

Within the Grid struct all 8 possible neighboring positions are contained within *offsets*.

```
struct Grid {
    static let offsets: [Position] = [
        (row: -1, col:  1), (row: 0, col:  1), (row: 1, col:  1),
        (row: -1, col:  0),                    (row: 1, col:  0),
        (row: -1, col: -1), (row: 0, col: -1), (row: 1, col: -1)
    ]
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your `norm` function could be written as: `return val % size`. Given your example, currently it would be `((12 % 10) + 10) % 10` which simplifies down to `(2 + 10) % 10` -> `12 % 10` -> `2`. What I mean is that the `(+ 10) % 10` doesn't do anything

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180840/what-is-the-shortest-code-to-get-surrounding-coordinates/44181515#44181515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're mapping the offsets, you need to add them to the cell's current position to get the absolute positions of its neighbouring cells. You're also mapping an array of `Position` tuples, so there will only be one argument in the map closure which will be a `Position` - so instead of `$0` and `$1`, you need `$0.row` and `$0.col`.

```
return Grid.offsets.map { (norm($0.row + cell.position.row, to: rows), norm($0.col + cell.position.col, to: cols)) }
```

Note that because of your `norm` function, this will wrap. For example, this function will say that the cell at `(row: 3, col: 0)` is next to the cell at `(row: 3, col: 9)`

Comment: thank you! i got it to work by accessing row as cell.position.0 and col as cell.position.1 per https://www.weheartswift.com/tuples-enums/

Comment: In my code, I assumed you defined `cell.position`as `struct Cell { var position: Position }`, but if you defined it as `(Int, Int)`, then it wouldn't know what row is. You'd either have to change `cell.position.row` to `cell.position.0` and `cell.position.col` to `cell.position.1` (bad in terms of readability) or change the definition of a cell's position to be a `Position` (good in terms of readability) because then you can use `cell.position.row` and `cell.position.col`